# How can I check if a users input is strictly alphabetical?

Tags: python, error-handling, user-input, try-except

I am currently working on the pseudocode of a project and it has just come to mind that, while I have a way of checking if User Input is strictly numerical, I have no idea of how to check if the input is strictly Alphabetical.

**For Example:**

```
def valueCheck_Int(question):

    while (True):
        try:
            return int(input(question))
        except:
            question = "That is not a valid integer, try again: "


def main():
    
    userInput = valueCheck_Int("Enter an integer: ")

    print(userInput)

main()
```

This piece of code checks if the user's input is strictly numerical, and will only break the loop until the user has entered an integer.

Is there any possible way to do this, but with string input being alphabetical, with no numbers at all?

Comment: Would the input contain spaces/punctuation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `str` type in Python have methods for checking it, you don't need try, except at all.

These methods called `isnumeric` and `isalpha`.

`isnumeric` - If a string is a number, it'll return True, otherwise return False.

`isalpha` - If a string is alphabetical, it'll return True, otherwise return False.

Code Example:

```
string = 'alphabetical'

if string.isnumeric():
    print('String is numeric!, it contains numbers and valid for integer casting!')
elif string.isalpha():
    print('String is alpha!, it contains alphabetical letters.')
```